# Implementing non-linear time delay

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, 555, feedback, delay

I have a feedback system including an OP-amp in comparator mode and a transistor, in present time it acts like a regulator, constantly limiting the current through the transistor to a certain value.
However, in order to not heat up and burn the transistor the system must be altered so that in the  "off-time", when the current is limited the transistor is completely off instead. (It is an p-channel MOSFET).

What I need to implement is an time delay in order to break the continuous regulation loop and instead have following pattern: "Check if current is too large" > "if too large shut MOSFET for a 0,5-3 seconds or so" "else, conduct as usual".

I need to implement the delay using as few components as possible. This far I have looked at 555-circuits and monostable multivibrators. They could be an option, but however, both require a bit too much components and space. RC-circuits don't seem to cut it as the feedback finds an equilibrium and avoids the delay filters.

I hereby ask for advice and example circuits.

P.S.

My circuit is an alteration of the following one:

[image]

Alternative solutions are also welcome.

Comment: Why not just sense transistor's temperature with a NTC and make a comparator woth hysteresis? It will turn on your regulator when transistor cools to a specified temperature and turn it off when t gets too hot. It is the most common way of overheating control.

Comment: What current are you trying to provide to your load?

Comment: A little SOT-23 microcontroller may well be one of the most *compact* solutions to this problem.  In terms of general strategy, rather than ever having the switch *partially* on it may be best to try to use pulse width modulation to run it at a desired average power, while essentially only every being fully on or fully off (or briefly in transition) - this will yield the best power efficiency and produce the least waste heat.  How fast your PWM cycle should be depends a lot on the time response of the load.